# How to map different queries for different database in one project in springboot?

Tags: java, database, oracle, azure, spring-boot

In my current project, I am doing migration from Oracle to Azure SQL Server. Right now, we need to integrate both database working with same queries. Depending on what I have on my configuration, project will connect with Oracle or Azure SQL.

Problem is, there are some queries that are not compatible for both database types. For instance, `nextval` works for Oracle, but not with Azure SQL:

In Oracle:

```
... values(unique_id_seq.nextval ...
```

In Azure SQL:

```
... values(NEXT VALUE FOR unique_id_seq, ...
```

Therefore, I think I will need to create two different queries and my project should know which database I am loading and it should map to correct query. Is this possible to achieve in springboot? I am pretty new to springboot..

(One of my co-worker said `If possible try to convert query into HQL or add the mapping entity, instead of creating separate queries.`, but I am not sure what this means.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Spring Boot with Hibernate.